# Intersection of maximal subgroups of PSL(2,q)

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G := PSL(2,2^r)$, and let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$ isomorphic to $PSL(2,2^s)$. I need to compute $H := M \cap M^g$ for $g \in G-M$. It seems to me that  $|H|$ must be  $2^r, 2^r\pm 1$ or $1$ (the latter may not hold for some values of $r$ and $s$). I think this is not difficult to prove, but the result sounds to be well-known. It would be appreciated if you introduce any references.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "the latter". I think that $|H| = |M|, 2^s, 2^s \pm 1$ or $1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt For example if $r=4$ and $s=2$ then for all $g \in G$ the subgroup $M^g \cap M$ is non-trivial. It seems true whenever $r=2s$ but I have not seen any proof of that.

Comment: You should edit the post to correct it. You have $2^r$ instead of $2^s$ in the possible orders of $|H|$, and I think you should say that an intersection of order $1$ is not possible when $r=2s$. I will think about the proof! Unfortunately we still have $|H|^2 < |G|$ in that case (although not by very much).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a partial answer, here is a sketch of a counting argument to show that, for $r=2s$, two subgroups $H,K \cong {\rm PSL}(2,s)$ cannot intersect trivially.  Suppose for a contradiction that $H \cap K=1$.

The total number of conjugates of $H$ in $G$ is $|G:H| = (2^r+1)2^s$. Of these, the $|H| = (2^r-1)2^s$ conjugates of $K$ under elements of $H$ are all distinct (otherwise some nontrivial element of $H$ would normalize $K$, but $K$ is self-normalizing), and they all intersect $H$ trivially.

Now $H$ has $2^{s-1}(2^s+1)$ cyclic subgroups of order $2^s-1$. Let $C$ be one of these. Then $C$ is centralized in $G$ by a cyclic subgroup of order $2^s+1$ that intersects $H$ trivially (since $C$ is self-centralizing in $H$). The $2^s$ conjugates of $H$ under the nontrivial elements of $D$ are all distinct, and their intersection with $H$ contains $C$. The proper subgroups of $H$ containing $C$ have orders $2^s-1$, $2(2^s-1)$ and $2^s(2^s-1)$. An intersection $H \cap H^d$ of order $2^s(2^s-1)$ is not possible (I'll leave the proof of that to you), so the intersections $H \cap H^d$ for $d \in D$ all contain the unique subgroup $C$ of order $2^s-1$.

Since there are $2^{s-1}(2^s+1)$ subgroups of $H$ of order $2^s-1$, there are at least $2^{2s-1}(2^s+1)$ conjugates of $H$ in $G$ that intersect $H$ in a subgroup of order $2^s-1$ or $2(2^s-1)$ and these, together with the $(2^r-1)2^s$ that intersect $H$ trivially, come to more than the total number of conjugates of $H$ in $G$, so we have a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think a similar argument shows that the converse is also true, i.e. $H \cap K = 1$ for some $g \in G$ iff $r \ne 2s$.